# joining two custom post types for wp_query

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I have two custom post types ("affiliate_codes" & "affiliate_tracker") that share a custom field ("affiliate_code"). In "affiliate_codes" I manage a master list of affiliate accounts (ie Affiliate Code, WP User, Percentage). In "affiliate_tracker", I have a form that adds new posts to the CPT passing fields such as Affiliate Code, Purchase Amt, etc.

I'm trying to create a report that is essentially a query that combines data from both of these CPTs, using the affiliate_code custom field to join the two CPTs together for the query.

A user could have more than one affiliate_code associated, so it would need to use the user ID passed in to grab all affiliate_codes associated to that user ID in 'affiliate_codes' CPT, and then retrieve all posts from 'affiliate_tracker' CPT that includes any of the codes associated to the user.

Is there a way to Join two custom post types as part of one query?

I initially tried to do this by nesting a second query within the main query.
Query 1 - pulling all posts from affiliate_tracker CPT and looping through.
Query 2 (nested inside the loop above) - uses affiliate code field to retrieve User from affiliate_code CPT

This works fine when I want to return all posts in affiliate_tracker. I also need to be able to filter the posts returned to only those associated with a specific user which is where I am struggling. Ideally I could have one query that combines the two CPTs by connecting posts via the shared 'affiliate_code' field and then can pull all posts from affiliate_tracker that have a code that is associated to a specific user. Not sure if this is possible.

Comment: how is the user id being saved?

Answer (score 0):

Of course m8 , u can do it easily.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => [ 'affiliate_codes', 'affiliate_tracker' ],
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Above query gives you the all posts of these post types , now using following link you can filter them based on meta values based on your needs

[Wordpress meta query parmeters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters)